# Is it good to make real router navigation during angular test or fakeAsync?

Tags: angular, angular-unit-test

While writing angular unit test for routing, is it okay to navigate with real values or we should use fakeAsync for router navigations?

**Option 1**

```
it('navigate to "home" takes you to /home', fakeAsync(() => {
        router.navigate(['home']);
        tick();
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/home');
 }));
```

**Option 2**

```
it('navigate to "home" takes you to /home', () => {
        router.navigate(['home']).then(() => {
            expect(location.path()).toBe('/home');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> As a rule you test the component, **not** the router, and care only if
>   the component navigates with the right address under the given
>   conditions.

You can create a mockRouter/spyRouter by using jasmine like this.

```
const routerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);
```

And then you can provide it to the testing module.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: Router,useValue: routerSpy }
  ]
});
```

And you can have a test spec like this.(example taken from the angular official doc)

```
    it('should tell ROUTER to navigate when hero clicked', () => {

  heroClick(); // trigger click on first inner <div class="hero">

  // args passed to router.navigateByUrl() spy
  const spy = router.navigateByUrl as jasmine.Spy;
  const navArgs = spy.calls.first().args[0];

  // expecting to navigate to id of the component's first hero
  const id = comp.heroes[0].id;
  expect(navArgs).toBe('/heroes/' + id,
    'should nav to HeroDetail for first hero');
});
```

Read more aboute [Routing component testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing#routing-component).